# Python - cant get 2 methods in class to share data

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying around with python/pygame.

I made a simple player class.

```
class Player():
  def __init__(self):
    self.posx = 10
    self.posy = 20


  def render (self):
    pygame.draw.rect(screen,(255,0,0), (self.posx,self.posy,100,100))

  def walk (self):
    self.posx += 10
```

render function:

```
def render():
  player = Player()
  player.walk()
  player.render()
```

And the loop:

```
running = True
while running:
  render()
  for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
      running = False
```

I assumed that this code would add 10 pixels to the x position every frame. But instead it updates the position to 20 the first time it renders and just stays there.

I tried printing the value and it does print every frame on the walk and render so the loop works correct, so why doesnt the position get updates?

Comment: I cannot see a loop.

Comment: Hmm yeah I left it out because it seemed inrelevant to me. but I added it now

Comment: You create a new player on each iteration. Thus resetting the coordinates. You need to create the player outside `render` function.

Comment: The render method recreate the instance of player everytime starting from the beginning again

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are re-creating the instance in every call to `render`.

```
player = Player()
def render(player): 
  player.walk()
```

This should work better:

```
running = True
player = Player()

while running:
  render(player)
  for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
      running = False
```

#### edit :

as timgeb, pointed in the now deleted post, the method render is quite unneeded. I left it for the OP to be more clear with the his original code style.

Comment: yeah I deleted mine because you were a bit faster and my post did not add much.

Comment: well, your thirty second extra thinking made me find a bug in my example post, and made it clear that the method is not needed. Thanks for sharing your post anyway.